# How to save Sparks MatrixFactorizationModel recommendProductsForUsers to Hbase

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, matrix-factorization

I am new to spark and I am want to save the output of recommendProductsForUsers to Hbase table. I found an example (https://sparkkb.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/save-javardd-to-hbase-using-saveasnewapihadoopdataset-spark-api-java-coding/) showing to use JavaPairRDD and saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset to save.

How can I convert `JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Rating[]>>` to `JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>` so that I can use saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset?

```
//Loads the data from hdfs
    MatrixFactorizationModel sameModel = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(jsc.sc(), trainedDataPath);  

//Get recommendations for all users
    JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Rating[]>> ratings3 = sameModel.recommendProductsForUsers(noOfProductsToReturn).toJavaRDD();
```

Comment: You want to save the model or the recommendations ?

Comment: @eliasah I want to save the recommendations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved the above problem, hope this will be helpful to someone.

```
    JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> hbasePuts1 = ratings3
                    .mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<Object, Rating[]>, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>() {

                        @Override
                        public Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> call(Tuple2<Object, Rating[]> arg0)
                                throws Exception {
                            Rating[] userAndProducts = arg0._2;
                            System.out.println("***********" + userAndProducts.length + "**************");
                            List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
                            Put put = null
                            String recommendedProduct = "";                         
                            for (Rating r : userAndProducts) {  

//Some logic here to convert Ratings into appropriate put command
// recommendedProduct = r.product; 

}

                            put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("recommendation"), Bytes.toBytes("product"),Bytes.toBytes(recommendedProduct));                     Bytes.toBytes("product"),Bytes.toBytes(response.getItems().toString()));

                            return new Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>(new ImmutableBytesWritable(), put);
                        }
                    });

            System.out.println("*********** Number of records in JavaPairRdd: "+ hbasePuts1.count() +"**************");
            hbasePuts1.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(newApiJobConfig.getConfiguration());
            jsc.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using mapToPair. From the same source you provided example(i changed types by hand):

```
JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> hbasePuts = javaRDD.mapToPair(
  new PairFunction<Tuple2<Object, Rating[]>, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>() {
@Override
public Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> call(Tuple2<Object, Rating[]> row) throws Exception {

   Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(0)));
   put.add(Bytes.toBytes("columFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("columnQualifier1"), Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(1)));
   put.add(Bytes.toBytes("columFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("columnQualifier2"), Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(2)));

       return new Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>(new ImmutableBytesWritable(), put);     
}
 });
```

It goes like this, you cretne new instance of put supplying it with row key in constructor, and then for each column you call add. and then you return the put created.

Answer (score 0):

We just open sourced Splice Machine and we have examples integrating MLIB with querying and storage into Splice Machine.  I do not know if this will help but thought I would let you know.

http://community.splicemachine.com/use-spark-libraries-splice-machine/

Thanks for the post, very cool.

Comment: Thanks Joh, this is very interesting, will look into this.